# non-www or non-https forwarding Nginx and Magento backend

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, web-server, magento

I am using following Nginx configuration block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MyDomain.co.uk www.MyDomain.co.uk *.MyDomain.co.uk;
    return 301 https://www.MyDomain.co.uk$request_uri;
       }

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name MyDomain.co.uk www.MyDomain.co.uk *.MyDomain.co.uk;
    access_log /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/httpdocs;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
...
...
...
}
```

this is to achieve that all traffic which comes to my website via following

- `http://MyDomain.co.uk`
- `http://www.MyDomain.co.uk`
- `https://MyDomain.co.uk`

should always be forwarded to `https://www.MyDomain.co.uk` but I am having 2 issues

1. Everything is fine but `https://MyDomain.co.uk` never forwards to `https://www.MyDomain.co.uk` not sure why but could it be due to fact that my certificate is only valid for `www.MyDomain.co.uk` and not for domain `MyDomain.co.uk`? but I have seen other posts in this forums where users are achieving this if I am not wrong?
2. After making above change of Nginx block configuration to forward non-https to https and non-www to www for some reason my Magento back-end is not working, I can login to backend fine but when I try to do anything like flushing the cache or any other function it always says following and nothing is done
   [image: magento_backend_issue]

Could it be because most of the settings of Nginx is under SSL block?

Comment: probably because your forms are submitting to http - hard to say without any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer to include full configuration.

Your `https://MyDomain.co.uk` doesn't forward to `https://www.MyDomain.co.uk` because you have the `MyDomain.co.uk` domain in your `https` block, which doesn't have any redirects.

You should remove `MyDomain.co.uk` and `*.MyDomain.co.uk` from your current `server` block that listens on `443` port, and you should add the following block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MyDomain.co.uk www.MyDomain.co.uk *.MyDomain.co.uk;
    return 301 https://www.MyDomain.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name MyDomain.co.uk *.MyDomain.co.uk;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    return 301 https://www.MyDomain.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.MyDomain.co.uk;
    access_log /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/vhosts/MyDomain.co.uk/httpdocs;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/MyDomain.co.uk.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

This way you will have a `server` block for redirecting the other domains, and then the main `server` block which will process the request.

So, you have three vhosts:

1) `http`, which redirects all requests to `www.MyDomain.co.uk`
2) `https`, which redirects `MyDomain.co.uk` and `*.MyDomain.co.uk` requests to `www.MyDomain.co.uk`
3) `https` for processing the final request to `www.MyDomain.co.uk`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? do you mean to change port 80 server block?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I've had some health problems and now I'm full back in action. You don't need to change the port 80 server block, it handles the redirects correctly already. However, you need to add a separate port 443 server block for the other domains you want to redirect to www.MyDomain.co.uk, and add the redirect there.